# file couldn't be opened because u don't have permission to view it

Tags: ios, xcode9.3

Why it showing this in project

[Project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAaT6.png) Why these files showing '?' as shown in picture?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear:  ***You don't have permission*** (not enough access privileges).

Answer (score 0):

You can check and update permissions with the help of: https://support.apple.com/kb/ph25247?locale=en_US

Comment: link is broken.